# why the extruded verts not lay down on ground

Tags: cloth-simulation

i have made the verts and extruded and added cloth simulation and below a plane ground. Why the verts not lay down on the ground. I have apply passive from physics tab.

[image]

[image]

**New Result**
[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to add some explanation as to what those images show and what steps you've taken to get to where you are now. Show screenshots of any relevant settings along with explanations where you can, describe what geometry you have in each example, what collision settings, anything else that is relevant.

Comment: @RichSedman A suggestion given by thibsert i have turn floor to collision and cloth (a verts line) i have extruded to 0.005 and got the above result (new result). Nothing special in the cloth setting. Just self collision on thats it. Rest default setting.

Answer (score 4):

Floor plane needs to be set as Collision, not Rigid Body.

Cloth needs Faces to work, not only verts. You should extrude your vertices by a small amount on Y. (Not to small : below 0.003 I had some strange results)

Comment: Good point about Cloth needing Faces. If it is really a requirement to have edges only then Soft Body might be a better fit.

Comment: The verts made as shown but its not landing on the floor or ground and verts getting stretch behind. Not like a thread its smoothly fall down

Comment: i have attach new gif file new result. Its not landing on the floor and scrolling behind

Comment: @RichSedman plz look at the result as mention in the answer. gif file attach in the question (new result)

Comment: @atek, it's not clear what you've changed to get the 'new result'. Please update your question with step by step results to how someone could set up the same situation. Any new info should ideally be in the original question rather than tagged on as comments to this answer.

Comment: @RichSedman update new result